# Appending to arr[0] where a = [[]]*n. Python

Tags: python

Why code:

```
hl = [[]]*3
hl[0].append(1)
return hl
```

gives [[1],[1],[1]] instead of [[1],[],[]]?

Comment: because `hl = [[]]*3` creates a list with three references *to the same empty list*. The same as if you did `empty = []; hl = [empty, empty, empty]`

Comment: A solution: `hl = [[] for _ in range(3)]`